# Quadratics with roots as integers; possible values of a

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Suppose $a$, $b$ are real numbers such that $a+b=12$ and both roots of the equation $x^2+ax+b=0$ are integers.

Determine all possible values of $a$.

I don't know how to go about doing this without long, messy casework.  I tries $(x-s)(x-r)=x^2+ax+b$ and got $-r-s=a$ and $rs=b$, but was unable to find all solutionss based on only these and $a+b=12$.  Could someone help me finish up?  Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your method, carried a little further, works. We have $-(r+s)+rs=12$. Rewrite as 
$$(r-1)(s-1)=13.$$

There are now not many possibilities, since $13$ is prime. Don't forget about negative numbers.

Answer (score 7):

Since $a + b = 12$

$$-(r+s) + rs = 12$$

Using Simon's favorite factoring trick:

$$(r-1)(s-1) - 1 = 12 \iff (r-1)(s-1) = 13$$

Only two possible solutions arise:

$r -1 = 1$ and $s -1 = 13$, therefore $r = 2$ and $s = 14$

$r -1 = -1$ and $s -1 = -13$, therefore $r = 0$ and $s = -12$

Therefore, $a = -16$ and $b = 28$

or

$a = 12$ and $b = 0$

Comment: who is Simon? :)

Comment: @Ant apparently this guy: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Simon%27s_Favorite_Factoring_Trick